# Exponential sum involving floor function

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, exponential-sums

Can one get cancellation in exponential sums such as, say,
$$
\sum_{n\sim N} e(\lfloor n^\theta\rfloor^\beta),
$$
for fixed positive $\theta,\beta\not\in\mathbb Z$? When $\theta < 1$, it seems possible without issue by grouping together values taken on by $\lfloor n^\theta\rfloor$ and then using exponent pairs, but for $\theta > 1$, this obviously doesn't work.

Comment: In principle, Taylor expansion expresses the phase locally as a bracket polynomial most of the time, so the problem reduces to obtaining cancellation for most of these bracket polynomials. This in turn is in principle achievable from the equidistribution theory of nilsequences but the calculations will be quite messy.

Comment: To give just one taste of the potential subtleties involved: the phase $e(\{\sqrt{2}n\}^2) = e((\sqrt{2}n - \lfloor \sqrt{2} n \rfloor)^2)$ expands to $e(-2\sqrt{2} n \lfloor \sqrt{2} n \rfloor)$, hence the sum $\sum_{n \sim N} e(-2\sqrt{2} n \lfloor \sqrt{2} n \rfloor)$ does not achieve cancellation despite the irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$ because $\int_0^1 e(\theta^2)\ d\theta \neq 0$.  For small values of $\theta,\beta$ you may be able to work things out by _ad hoc_ calculation, but to have any hope of a general theory one would probably have to use the langauge of nilsequences.

Comment: How with nilsequences might one be able to anticipate that $\sum_{n\sim N} e(-2\sqrt{2}n\lfloor \sqrt{2}n\rfloor)$ does not have cancellation (and when slight variants do)?

Comment: $e(-2\sqrt{2}n\lfloor \sqrt{2} n \rfloor)$ can be written as the piecewise nilsequence $F(g(n) H({\bf Z)})$ in the Heisenberg nilmanifold $H({\bf R})/H({\bf Z})$ with $H(R) = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & R & R \\ 0 & 1 & R \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $g(n) = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2\sqrt{2} n & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & \sqrt{2} n \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and a suitable piecewise smooth $F$.  In this case, $g(n) H({\bf Z)}$ is not equidistributed in the entire nilmanifold, but in a one-dimensional subtorus, on which $F$ turns out to behave like $\alpha \mapsto e(\{\alpha\}^2)$ in suitable coordinates.

Comment: A general equidistribution theorem of Leibman states that any polynomial sequence $g(n)\Gamma$ in a nilmanifold will equidistribute in a finite union of subnilmanifolds, but the precise subnilmanifolds involved depend on the algebraic relations between the coefficients of $g$.  In this case, the coefficients are such that the submanifolds are unusually low dimension, so much so that $F$ ceases to be mean zero.  For your specific problem perhaps the best way forward is to extend Leibman's theorem to "real-exponent polynomials" in which $g$ can contain terms like $n^\theta$ ...

Comment: ... but continue to use local Taylor expansion to handle the exponentiation to power $\beta$. Richter's Hardy field extension https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.02028 of Leibman's theorem seems relevant for this purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me try to provide a partial answer in the case when $0<\beta<2$ much in line with what Terry suggested in the comments. Perhaps it is possible to extend this method to all $\beta>2$ but the computations get more complicated.

Using Taylor expansion and $\lfloor n^\theta\rfloor=n^\theta-\{n^\theta\}$ we obtain
$$
\lfloor n^\theta\rfloor^\beta = n^{\theta\beta}+\mathrm{o}_{n\to\infty}(1)
$$
when $0<\beta<1$ and
$$
\lfloor n^\theta\rfloor^\beta = n^{\theta\beta}-\beta \{n^\theta\}n^{\theta(\beta-1)}+\mathrm{o}_{n\to\infty}(1)
$$
when $1<\beta<2$. In the first case, one has $\sum_{1\leq n\leq N}e(\lfloor n^\theta\rfloor^\beta)\approx\sum_{1\leq n\leq N}e(n^{\theta\beta})$ and hence cancellation occurs exactly when $\theta\beta$ is not an integer (one can use the Kusmin-Landau inequality/ van der Corput method to obtain good bounds on the cancellation in this case, see for example the book by Graham and Kolesnik: https://doi.org/10.1017/CBO9780511661976).

So lets focus on the second case when $1<\beta<2$, which seems more complicated. Using the notation from the comments, let
$$
H(\mathbb{R})=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & \mathbb{R} & \mathbb{R} \\ 0 & 1 & \mathbb{R} \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}~~~\text{and}~~~H(\mathbb{Z})=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & \mathbb{Z} & \mathbb{Z} \\ 0 & 1 & \mathbb{Z} \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Consider $G=\mathbb{R}\times H(\mathbb{R})$ and $\Gamma=\mathbb{Z}\times H(\mathbb{Z})$ and take their quotient to obtain the nilmanifold $G/\Gamma=\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}\times H(\mathbb{R})/H(\mathbb{Z})$. Consider the function
$$
F\left(u,\begin{pmatrix} 1 & x & z \\ 0 & 1 & y \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\right)= e(u-z+x\lfloor y\rfloor),
$$
which is a Riemann integrable and well defined function on $X$. (This is because $(\{x\},\{y\}, \{z-x\lfloor y\rfloor\})$ is a fundamental domain for the Heisenberg nilmanifold, see here for details: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilmanifold). Now consider the sequence
$$
g(n)=\left(n^{\theta\beta},\begin{pmatrix} 1 & \beta n^{\theta(\beta-1)} & \beta n^{\theta\beta} \\ 0 & 1 & n^\theta \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\right)
$$
Note that with this choice of $X$, $F$,and $g$ we have
$$
\frac{1}{N}\sum_{1\leq n\leq N}e(\lfloor n^\theta\rfloor^\beta) \approx \frac{1}{N}\sum_{1\leq n\leq N}e(n^{\theta\beta}-\beta \{n^\theta\}n^{\theta(\beta-1)})=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{1\leq n\leq N} F(g(n)).
$$
Due to the main result in https://arxiv.org/abs/2006.02028 we know that the sequence $g(n)$ is uniformly distributed in the nilmanifold $X$ if and only if $(n^{\theta\beta},\beta n^{\theta(\beta-1)},n^\theta)$ is uniformly distributed in $\mathbb{T}^3=\mathbb{R}^3/\mathbb{Z}^3$. So if neither $\theta\beta$ nor $\theta(\beta-1)$ are integers then the sequence $g(n)$ is uniformly distributed in $X$ and hence
$$
\frac{1}{N}\sum_{1\leq n\leq N} F(g(n))\rightarrow \int F\,d\mu_X,
$$
where $\mu_X$ is the natural (and normalized) Haar measure on $X$. But since $\int F\,d\mu_X=0$, it follows that
$$
\frac{1}{N}\sum_{1\leq n\leq N}e(\lfloor n^\theta\rfloor^\beta)\rightarrow 0.
$$

Note that if $\theta(\beta-1)$ is an integer then the sequence $g(n)$ is not uniformly distributed on the entire nilmanifold $X$ but rather distributes uniformly on a sub-nilmanifold $Y\subset X$. But due to the simple nature of $F$, it is not so hard to see that for any such sub-nilmanifold $Y$ one has $\int F\,d\mu_Y=0$, which in turn still implies cancellation. So the only condition seems to be that $\theta\beta$ is not an integer.

Please let me know if this is helpful or if you have any questions.

Comment: If one tries to use this for $\beta$ larger than $2$, and encounters in the Taylor expansion terms like $\{n^\theta\}^2n^{\theta (\beta - 2)}$, is there a systematic way to find appropriate nilmanifolds to capture these terms?